# What is ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME/TYPE for?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

When trying to create a new Contact group, I found that the new group cannot be seen in the mobile, unless I set `ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME and ACCOUNT_TYPE`:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> o = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
o.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Groups.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, groupTitle)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE, true)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME, "local@ztespecial_local.com") // without these two lines the new group will not be shown
      .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "local@ztespecial_local.com")
      .build());
try {
    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, o);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ContactsManager", "Failed to create new contact group: "+e);
    return;
}
```

By listing all groups, I found that all groups which `ACCOUNT_TYPE/NAME` is null will not be seen in system's Contact application, even its `Groups.VISIBLE` is true.

Is there a guideline that what value I should set for a new group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are possibly multiple accounts for contacts in Android, it is possible that the system's Contact application is only showing interested accounts. So, one proper way is to get default account name and type.

Here is a function to get default account name and type:

```
private String[] getDefaultAccountNameAndType() {
    String accountType = "";
    String accountName = "";

    long rawContactId = 0;
    Uri rawContactUri = null;
    ContentProviderResult[] results = null;

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(); 

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null).build());

    try {
        results = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        ops.clear();
    }

    for (ContentProviderResult result : results) {
        rawContactUri = result.uri;
        rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);
    }

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
            RawContacts.CONTENT_URI
            , new String[] {RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME}
            , RawContacts._ID+"=?"
            , new String[] {String.valueOf(rawContactId)}
            , null);

    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        if(!c.isAfterLast()) {
            accountType = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE));
            accountName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME));
        }
    }

    getContentResolver().delete(rawContactUri, null, null);

    c.close();
    c = null;

    return new String[] { accountName, accountType };
}
```

Then we can set them when creating a new group:

```
String accountNameType[] = getDefaultAccountNameAndType();
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> o = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
o.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Groups.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValue(Groups.TITLE, groupTitle)
      .withValue(Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE, true)
      .withValue(Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountNameType[0])
      .withValue(Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountNameType[1])
      .build());
try {
  getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, o);
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e("ContactsManager", "Failed to create new contact group: "+e);
  return;
}
```

Comment: This works as on today. I am able to create the contact group by the above method. Thanks @Deqing

Answer (score 0):

The accounts are allways of a certain type. For what kind of accounts do you want to create a group? Are these Google Contacts or other contact types?

Account type can be "com.google" for example when it is a Google account. But you can also use your own custom account type. Then you need an account-authenticator see: https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator.html